# NoClassDefFoundError when using resteasy @Path annotation

Tags: java, jax-rs, noclassdeffounderror, resteasy, buildpath

I have a Controller class annotated with `@Path` annotation from resteasy. It runs normally.

But when I extend this class from a BaseController, that is located in another project (included in this project build path), I get an error of `NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to reference to BaseController.

**WORKS:**

```
@Path("/")
public class Controller {...}
```

**WORKS:**

```
@Path("/")
public class Controller extends BaseController {...} //BaseControler from the same project
```

**WORKS:**

```
public class Controller extends BaseController {...} //BaseControler from other project
```

**DOESN´T WORK:** (NoClassDefFoundError)

```
@Path("/")
public class Controller extends BaseController {...} //BaseControler from other project
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: how is your app packaged in the case where it doesn't work?

Comment: Class Controller belongs to a package in "Project1". The Application class belongs to a sibling package also in "Project1". And the BaseController class belongs to a package in another "Project2", that is included in the "Project1" build path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be the same from this question:
[Java project unable to refer to another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128419/java-project-unable-to-refer-to-another-project?rq=1)
In that case, the "OtherProjectClass" could not be instatied.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you deploy does not contain the `BaseController.class` file. In order to test it: unpack (i.e unzip) the deployed `war`, `jar` or `ear` file and check if the file `BaseController.class` is in the right place there. Most probably the file is no there.